# Restarting Heroku on S3 Bucket upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, heroku, plotly-dash

I have a Python Dash app hosted on Heroku, with csv files referenced from an S3 Bucket.

I want the app to use the new csv data as soon as it is uploaded (upon refresh). But I don't want it to go to the S3 Bucket every refresh.

At present, I need to do "heroku restart" but that requires me to log in to Heroku which obviously takes time logging in via the CLI.

Is there a way to automate the restart. Not scheduled, but when there is a change to the S3 Bucket?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Comment: Using read_csv (pandas)